# SQL Server 2008 R2 pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pagination

I need to implement pagination for my union query, but I get error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.". I followed example I found from this [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/1427310/3186427.aspx#3186427).

```
select * 
  from (select Id, 
               row_number() OVER (order by Id asc) as RowNumber 
          from (select Id 
                  from (select Id 
                          from Table1) as table1 
                union all 
                select Id 
                  from (select Id 
                          from Table2) as table2)) as t Derived 
  WHERE RowNumber > 5 
    and RowNumber <= 10
```

Comment: what is happening? Do you get an error?

Comment: Updated answer to contain error message.

Comment: I've never liked SQL Server's error locations, but I'm counting 12 lines in your code. Is there anything you haven't pasted?

Comment: I just removed real column names, so it could be shorter than real query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT u.* 
  FROM (SELECT t.id, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) as rownum 
          FROM (SELECT t1.id 
                  FROM TABLE1 t1
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT t2.id 
                  FROM TABLE2 t2) as t) AS u
 WHERE u.rownum > 5 
   AND u.rownum <= 10
```

It looks to me that your query was missing a closing bracket for a derived table called "derived", but there wasn't the need for the subqueries in the UNION so I've removed them.

Comment: Seems like it wasn't a missing bracket, but a missing table alias (for the UNION ALL subselect). Anyway, you've restructured it much better.

Comment: I like it.  A slight derivation I use for paging is this:    `SELECT TOP(5) u.* 
  FROM (SELECT t.id, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.id) as rownum 
          FROM (SELECT t1.id 
                  FROM TABLE1 t1
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT t2.id 
                  FROM TABLE2 t2) as t) AS u
 WHERE u.rownum > 5'

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move one parenthesis:

`from Table2) as table2)) as t Derived` should read `from Table2) as table2) as t) Derived`

You could also remove some of the subqueries that make Table1 into table1 and Table2 in to table2 but I assume there's some other reaon for those in there (like this is based on another query that is more complicated)

Comment: No it's not really more complicated and it worked fine with your advice, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
  from (select Id, 
               row_number() OVER (order by Id asc) as RowNumber 
          from (select Id 
                  from Table1 as table1 
                union all 
                select Id 
                  from Table2)p)t 
  WHERE RowNumber > 5 
    and RowNumber <= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select from subquery then  you have to give alias for it. You have 2 outer subqueries but only one with alias. Should be: `from Table2) as tabl2) as t) as t`