# How to create t-sql to load next n-amount of records?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, pagination

I need an example of creating t-sql query to load next 10 records (depends on the default row amount in grid).

the same kind of linq has to skip rows.

So for example I have 100K of results I need to load just 10 between 100 and 110 records and so on. The idea is to make it page load very fast

I need also to build paging for my grid so I need to know how many records in total

Comment: There are countless SO questions about pagination -- I'd find a duplicate if I knew what database you were using.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I think t-sql implies ms sql server.

Comment: @zespri: TSQL is also supported by Sybase ;)  But yes, SQL Server is what I would put money on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 R2 pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871523/sql-server-2008-r2-pagination), but there's [lots to choose from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+pagination)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MS SQL 2005/2008 you can do something like this

```
with cte
as
(
    select row_number() over (order by ID) RowNumber, *
    from MyTable
) 
select *
from cte
where RowNumber between 10 and 20
```

[Edit]
With total count column

```
select *
from
(
    select
        row_number() over (order by ID) RowNumber, 
        count(*) over() TotalRowCount,
        *
    from MyTable
) tt
where RowNumber between 10 and 20
```

Comment: Alex can I also return total rows count in the same query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT YourColumn1, YourColumn2, RN
FROM
(
   SELECT YourTable1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourTable1PK) RN
   FROM YourTable1
) sq
 WHERE sq.rn BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: can I also return total rows count in the same query?

Comment: Yes you can return the total row count.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this.  It should be fast as long as you have an index on the Records.Id column.

```
select *
from 
    (select
        row_number() over (order by Id) as [RowNum],
        count(*) over() as [TotalCount],
        Id from @Records) as R
where
    [RowNum] between @StartRow and (@StartRow + @PageSize)
```

Check out MSDN to find out more about the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function.

Comment: Chris can I return in this query total row count?

Comment: Yes, you can add COUNT(*) as an aggregate window function.